# How to show multiple values in same field Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, jsx, react-dom

I want to show mouse coordinates on a textbox.
By doing this

```
<TextField
      id="t2"
      floatingLabelText={this.state.mouseX}
/>
```

I get the mouse X coordinate

On the same field along with this X coordinate i also want to show the Y coordinate. And i am writing this

```
<TextField
          id="t2"
          floatingLabelText={this.state.mouseX, this.state.mouseY}
/>
```

which is only giving me the Y coordinate.

How can i show both values in the SAME FIELD ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`floatingLabelText` likely takes a string, so it's up to you to combine the values into a single string:

```
floatingLabelText={`${this.state.mouseX}, ${this.state.mouseY}`}
```

Comment: Thank you SimpleJ for the swift answer. much appreciated. its working. However I would like to ask what's the $ sign is for?

Comment: That's for placing variables in the string. [Here's](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) an MDN article about template literals.